# How to maintain ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

There are the entities `Cookbook`, `Recipe`. It's a ManyToMany relation: a cookbook can have multiple recipes and a recipe can be assigned to multiple cookbooks. So I added the entity `CookbookRecipe` and connected the entities as OneToMany.

Where to put a method to add/remove the relation between `Cookbook` and `Recipe` - does this method has to add a new `CookbookRecipe` and add this `CookbookRecipe` to `Cookbook` and `Recipe`?
In my understanding I would expect a

```
public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
   CookbookRecipe relation = new CookbookRecipe();
   relation.setCookbook(this);
   relation.setRecipe(recipe);
   this.cookbookRecipes.add( relation );
}
```

Is this the right direction?
Would I add this method to the Cookbook DAO or Recipe DAO or put this into a service?

```
@Entity
public class Cookbook {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private Collection<CookbookRecipe> cookbookRecipes;
    private Collection<CookbookSortlevel> cookbookSortlevels;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Cookbook cookbook = (Cookbook) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(cookbook.id) : cookbook.id != null) return false;
        if (title != null ? !title.equals(cookbook.title) : cookbook.title != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cookbook", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Collection<CookbookRecipe> getCookbookRecipes() {
        return cookbookRecipes;
    }

    public void setCookbookRecipes(Collection<CookbookRecipe> cookbookRecipes) {
        this.cookbookRecipes = cookbookRecipes;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cookbook")
    public Collection<CookbookSortlevel> getCookbookSortlevels() {
        return cookbookSortlevels;
    }

    public void setCookbookSortlevels(Collection<CookbookSortlevel> cookbookSortlevels) {
        this.cookbookSortlevels = cookbookSortlevels;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cookbook_recipe", schema = "", catalog = "")
public class CookbookRecipe {
    private Integer id;
    private Recipe recipe;
    private Cookbook cookbook;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        CookbookRecipe that = (CookbookRecipe) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        return result;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Recipe getRecipe() {
        return recipe;
    }

    public void setRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        this.recipe = recipe;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cookbook_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable=false,insertable=false,updatable=false )
    public Cookbook getCookbook() {
        return cookbook;
    }

    public void setCookbook(Cookbook cookbook) {
        this.cookbook = cookbook;
    }
}


@Entity
public class Recipe {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String text;

    private Collection<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "text")
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Recipe recipe = (Recipe) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(recipe.id) : recipe.id != null) return false;
        if (title != null ? !title.equals(recipe.title) : recipe.title != null) return false;
        if (text != null ? !text.equals(recipe.text) : recipe.text != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (text != null ? text.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe")
    public Collection<RecipeIngredient> getRecipeIngredients() {
        return recipeIngredients;
    }

    public void setRecipeIngredients(Collection<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients) {
        this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
    }
}
```

Are there any github projects handling this you could suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This is, for me, the right direction. The code looks good

I think you should add it in the CookBookDAO because the Cookbook contains Recipes not the opposite